# Load an UTF8 JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json, unicode

I try to parse a JSON file and I have an error when I want to print a JSON value that is HTML string.

The error is : `Traceback (most recent call last): File "parseJson.py", line 11, in <module> print entryContentHTML.prettify() UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u02c8' in position 196: ordinal not in range(128)`

```
import json
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('cat.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print data["entryLabel"]
entryContentHTML = BeautifulSoup(data["entryContent"])  
print entryContentHTML.prettify()
```

What is the common way to load a json file with UTF8 specification ?

Comment: You should really always include the full traceback; I erroneously followed your hint it was the JSON loading that was the problem, but your traceback will show it to be either the first or the second `print` statement instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the JSON just fine. It is your *`print` statement* that fails.

You are trying to print to a console or terminal that is configured for ASCII handling only. You'll either have to alter your console configuration or explicitly encode your output:

```
print data["entryLabel"].encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

and

```
print entryContentHTML.prettify().encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

Without more information about your environment it is otherwise impossible to tell how to fix your configuration (if at all possible).

Comment: I've try this before but I have this error `TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: @ChesterMcAllister: then you are using Python 2 and the error *is elsewhere entirely*. Please include the full traceback of your errors, **always**.